# Forcing file text/plain display on csv file from href link

Tags: iis, csv, text, mime-types

I want the users of my webapp to be able to click an href link leading directly to the content of .csv files located on the IIS server, just as if it was a .txt file. I don't want the browser to open the download file dialog which obviously forces the users to download the file in order to see it quickly and that's not what I want.

In a nutshell, (how) can we force the browsers to display csv files as text/plain without having the hand on the http requests (href link) ? Is it possible in IIS 7 ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe I should just create some special page taking the filepath as parameter and dumping the file content as is...

Comment: The easiest way is to just set the .csv Mime Type to text/plain in IIS !